# Laravel - Relaciones usando Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

estoy tratando de crear una relacion de campos usando eloquent de laravel, actualmente lo tengo funcionando así:

```
$empleos = Empleos::latest()->paginate(50);
return $empleos;
```

me retorna todos los empleos correctamente, mi problema es que hay campos que vienen desde otra tabla externa, la logica seria la siguiente:

```
$empleos = Empleos::latest()->paginate(50)->join('empresa','empresa.id''=','empreos.empresa');
return $empleos;
```

por lo cual me tira un error de que `join` no es identificado: `Method join does not exist.`

Alguien sabe que puedo hacer ante este caso, usando eloquent.

JSON de como deberia quedar:

> Actual:

```
    data: [
    {
    id: 1,
    titulo: "Programador Android Jr.",
    empresa: 1,
    ...
    }]
```

> Como deberia ser:

```
data: [
        {
        id: 1,
        titulo: "Programador Android Jr.",
        empresa: "Empresa numero 1",
        ...
            }]
```

Estructuras
tabla **empleos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tabla **empresa**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿usas HasMany, OneToOne o HasOne en tus modelos?

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente reordena tu consulta de este modo

```
$empleos = Empleos::join('empresa','empresa.id''=','empreos.empresa')
                    ->latest()
                    ->paginate(50);
return $empleos;
```

1. Es decir después de llamar al modelo `Empleos` accede al método `join`
2. Después el método `latest()` que es similar a `orderBy()`
3. Finalmente pagina los resultados con `paginate(50)`
4. Recuerda siempre terminar la query con `;` por que en tu pregunta te hacia falta

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para poder indicarle que en vez de el id te muestre el nombre de la empresa has esto

```
$empleos = Empleos::select("empleos.id", "empleos.titulo", "empresa.nombre")
                  ->join('empresa','empresa.id''=','empreos.empresa')
                        ->latest()
                        ->paginate(50);
    return $empleos;
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

Antes del `join`le pase el método `select()` y le indique cuales columnas y de que tabla necesito; de este modo

```
select("empleos.id", "empleos.titulo", "empresa.nombre")
```

> Solo te queda a tu verificar y colocar en caso de ser necesario el
>   nombre de las tablas y columnas; es decir si la tabla empleos de donde sacas > el titulo del empleo tiene la columna `titulo` usa esa, en caso contrario
>   coloca el nombre adecuado y asi con cada una

**segunda actualización**

A como entiendo tus tablas, una empresa tiene muchos empleos o puestos de empleo; por lo cual tu join me parece esta mal planteado; por lo cual debería ser de este modo **asumiendo que tu otro modelo se llama Empresa, si no colocale el adecuado**

```
$empleos = Empresa::select("empresa.id", "empleos.titulo", "empresa.nombre")
                  ->join('empleos','empresa.id', '=','empleos.empresa')
                        ->latest()
                        ->paginate(50);
```

Comment: me esta mezclando las dos tablas en un solo nodo, como podría quedar de la forma en que he actualizado mi pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: @DoubleM es decir necesitas que en lugar del id de la empresa te muestre el nombre de dicha empresa?

Comment: Así es compañero!

Comment: listo actualicé mi respuesta @DoubleM

Comment: Me sigue retornando lo mismo, no modifica el nombre de la empresa :/

Comment: agrega en tu pregunta la estructura de las tablas involucradas @DoubleM

Comment: solamente es la tabla **empresa** como clave foranea y empleos que es la principal.

Comment: Todo listo señor! agregado a me pregunta